# HightChart set new data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I initialize highchart with date and value like this :

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: 
        [
             [Date.parse("01/02/2017"),11],
             [Date.parse("02/02/2017"),22],
        ]

    },{
        name: 'Tehran',
        data: 
        [
             [Date.parse("01/02/2017"),33],
             [Date.parse("02/02/2017"),44],
        ]      
    }]
```

> In above example `chartArray` is successfully added to HighChart.

Now I want to to set new data in chart and I use `HighChart.series[0].setData()` method to do this.

**JS:**

```
 $('#btnUpdate').('click', function(){
    $.post('/Reporst/GetReportsJson/', data, function (dataR) {
       var chartArray = []; //for chart value
       var dateArray = []; // for chart date, X Axis
       for (var i in dataR) {
          for (var ii in dataR[i].finalChart) {  
             dateArray.push(dataR[i].finalChart[ii].date1);
             chartArray.push(parseInt(dataR[i].finalChart[ii].value));
          }
       HighChart.series[i].setData(chartArray);      
       dateArray = []; chartArray = [];
   }
})
```

With this code I only set `new data` to chart, My Question Is : How can I set `new date`, `new data` and `new label` for chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data of a series is formed of an array that contains, per data point, one array of two elements with the date as the first element (in your case) and the value as the second, as you can see in the first part of the code.

```
data: 
[ // Data is an array
     [Date.parse("01/02/2017"),11], // Each point is an array too
     [Date.parse("02/02/2017"),22],
]
```

So, when you populate the `chartArray` to do a `setData()`, it should have the same format, like this:

```
$('#btnUpdate').('click', function(){
    $.post('/Reporst/GetReportsJson/', data, function (dataR) {
       var chartArray = []; //for chart value
       for (var i in dataR) {
          for (var ii in dataR[i].finalChart) {  
             var date = dataR[i].finalChart[ii].date1;
             var value = parseInt(dataR[i].finalChart[ii].value);
             chartArray.push([Date.parse(date), value]); // One array with [date, value] per point, as stated above
          }
       }
       HighChart.series[i].setData(chartArray);      
       chartArray = [];
   }
})
```

Comment: How can set label name?

Comment: I found the solution, `HighChart.legend.allItems[0].update({name:i});`

Comment: I was just writting xD Glad you found it :-)

Comment: @Jorge_Fuentes_González   I'm looking for make animate chart when set data, But anyone of solution doesn't work for me, do you know why?

Comment: Highcharts is a bit picky with redraw animations. You can try to disable redraw when you set the data (by setting the second parameter to false: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData) and then do a `chart.redraw()`. Don't really know if this fixes it, but is worth a try.

Comment: Ok, I think that I know what is happening. If you setData of one series while other one is set, the animation is broken. Try the thing I said before.

Comment: It doesn't work and I found the problem, The problem occurred when I update labels with this: `chartM.series[i].update({name :i});`. If I remove this line everything work well.